# Printing issue in silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-5.0

Hi I am new to Silverlight. I have created Identity Card in silverlight. When I print that on A4 size paper, content is print on upper left side and print full content. but when i print on small size of paper, half portion of left side is not print. I dont know what is the problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Adjust your design as per paper of a4 and half both that's it not one can do work behalf you you have to show your code or try your self

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ViewBox Component around your control to Adjust the size to what you are printing. You can use the PrintableArea in the PrintPageEventArgs when the printpage event is fired.  You can even dynamically add the ViewBox around the item you are printing.